# Bash date case not correct

Tags: bash, date, bsd

I am using the following in a bash script

```
echo $(date +'%Y/%b')
```

I expect "2018/may" but what I actually get is "2018/May".
Is there anything I can do to make sure the month is lowercase?
I am running in a BSD jail.

Comment: Try `echo $(date +'%Y/%b') | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`

Comment: or `date +'%Y/%b' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As man date does not show help about lowercase month, I would just pipe it

```
echo $(date +'%Y/%b') | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Comment: On BSD systems, `man date` doesn't tell you about any of the date format options, those are part of `man strftime`. See my answer for a link.

Comment: Hi. that works but can I use it inline? Like www.mydomain.com/$(date +'%Y/%b') | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'/somemoreURLhere

Comment: Ah. Try  `www.mydomain.com/$(date +'%Y/%b' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')/somemoreURLhere` does it work?

Answer (score 2):

The command in your question is identical to simply:

```
date +'%Y/%b'
```

The date command itself has no options for lower case dates ([`man strftime`](http://man.freebsd.org/strftime) for details), but you can force case within bash using [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
$ x="$(date '+%Y/%b')"
$ x="${x,,}"
$ printf '%s\n' "$x"
2008/may
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I really wanted to avoid using vars. I did see this "$(LC_ALL=nn_NO.UTF-8 date +'%-d-%B-%Y')", which works but is the wrong language. I tried en_US but it was upper case. Any idea if this is possible? Sorry, noob here.

Comment: @Chris, nn_NO is Norwegian, and I think most of the Scandinavian countries don't normally capitalize their months. So .. you're not applying *case control*, here, you're just localizing to somewhere that has the case you want. :) If you really want to apply lower case in a pipeline, then the `tr` option is the way to go. `$(date '+%Y/%b' | awk '{print tolower()}')` would do as well. While awk might be a bit heavier than `tr`, it might allow you to address other challenges not mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The month is spelled with a capital first letter in English, that's why there is no format string to get the month in lower case.

In `bash`, using a lower-case-typed variable:

```
typeset -l now
now=$(date +'%Y/%b')
printf 'Date is %s\n' "$now"
```

This will output

```
Date is 2018/may
```

Comment: Apparently `typeset` is obsolete in bash. Use `declare` instead.

Comment: @glennjackman `bash` uses both, and probably allows `typeset` for alignment with the `ksh93` shell. `typeset -l` does the same thing in both shells. I found no obsolete marker for this in the `bash` sources.

Comment: bash v4.3.48: `help typeset` ... ``Obsolete.  See `help declare'.``

Comment: @glennjackman In `bash` 4.4.19: "A synonym for 'declare'.  See 'help declare'."

Comment: yes, the help text and the manual are different. Nevertheless +1 for typeset -l

Comment: Yes, that is what I said